# I am learning typescript Why does the array defining show error here?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am learning typescript 
Why does the array defining show error here?
//tried (string | number)[]

```
interface IState {
  orgTypes: Array<orgTypes>;  //shows error here

  orgType: string;
}

const data: IState = {
  orgType: "",

  orgTypes: [
    { id: "1", name: "Vendor" },
    { id: "2", name: "Supplier" },
    { id: "3", name: "Vendor and Supplier" }
  ]
};
```

Comment: where is `orgTypes` defined ? what error are you getting ?

Comment: ^^ that is, where is the **type** `orgTypes` (which you've used in `Array<orgTypes>`) defined? (The *property*, of course, is defined by the interface.)

Comment: inside const data

Comment: @NewBeeCoder - There are no types defined by the construct starting with `const data`. There's a big difference between *types* and runtime data. Types are a programming- and compile-time thing (in TypeScript).

Comment: how do I write this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not defining a type called `orgTypes` anywhere. From the question and comment, I suspect you want something like this:

```
// Define an `OrgType` type
interface OrgType {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

// Define an `IState` type
interface IState {
  orgTypes: OrgType[]; // Or Array<OrgType>; if you prefer, same thing
  orgType: string;
}

// Define runtime data using those types
const data: IState = {
  orgType: "",

  orgTypes: [
    { id: "1", name: "Vendor" },
    { id: "2", name: "Supplier" },
    { id: "3", name: "Vendor and Supplier" }
  ]
};
```

*(On the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Define%20an%20%60OrgType%60%20type%0D%0Ainterface%20OrgType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Define%20an%20%60IState%60%20type%0D%0Ainterface%20IState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20orgTypes%3A%20OrgType%5B%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Or%20Array%3COrgType%3E%3B%20if%20you%20prefer%2C%20same%20thing%0D%0A%20%20%20%20orgType%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Define%20runtime%20data%20using%20those%20types%0D%0Aconst%20data%3A%20IState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20orgType%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20orgTypes%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%221%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22Vendor%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%222%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22Supplier%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%223%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22Vendor%20and%20Supplier%22%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B))*

If you don't want to define an actual interface for `OrgType`, that's fine, you can do it inline as well:

```
// Define an `IState` type
interface IState {
  orgTypes: {id: string; name: string;}[];
  orgType: string;
}

// Define runtime data using those types
const data: IState = {
  orgType: "",

  orgTypes: [
    { id: "1", name: "Vendor" },
    { id: "2", name: "Supplier" },
    { id: "3", name: "Vendor and Supplier" }
  ]
};
```

*(On the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Define%20an%20%60IState%60%20type%0D%0Ainterface%20IState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20orgTypes%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20string%3B%20name%3A%20string%3B%7D%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20orgType%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Define%20runtime%20data%20using%20those%20types%0D%0Aconst%20data%3A%20IState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20orgType%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20orgTypes%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%221%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22Vendor%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%222%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22Supplier%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%223%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22Vendor%20and%20Supplier%22%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B))*

But almost any time I see someone define something inline like that, they end up needing it again elsewhere, so...

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

There is no type `orgTypes`, you declared it as a variable name. I guess you want to declare a type which you can like this

```
type orgs = {id: string, name: string}

interface IState {
  orgTypes: Array<orgs>;

  orgType: string;
}
```